# How to get the parent dir location

Tags: python, path

this code is get the templates/blog1/page.html  in b.py:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.join('templates', 'blog1/page.html'))
```

but i want to get the parent dir location:

```
aParent
   |--a
   |  |---b.py
   |      |---templates
   |              |--------blog1
   |                         |-------page.html
   |--templates
          |--------blog1
                     |-------page.html
```

and  how to get the aParent location

thanks

**updated:**

this is right:

```
dirname=os.path.dirname
path = os.path.join(dirname(dirname(__file__)), os.path.join('templates', 'blog1/page.html'))
```

or

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))
```

Comment: So you want to get `blog1` or `a` ? And where is your current file located?

Comment: do you understand what your code is doing?

Comment: yes , it get the templates/blog1/page.html

Comment: `os.path.join('templates', 'blog1/page.html')` looks strange to me. You are mixing things up. Either `os.path.join('templates', 'blog1', 'page.html')` or `'templates/blog1/page.html'`. And much easier would be `os.path.abspath(os.path.join('templates', 'blog1', 'page.html'))` then

Comment: @zjm: no, you don't *get* that page. It's not some blackbox that you could just use to get the template file. It performs a series of trivial small steps, and if you could understand them, you wouldn't have this question.

Comment: so  how to get the page  and the 'a' dir location ??

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You can apply dirname repeatedly to climb higher: `dirname(dirname(file))`. This can only go as far as the root package, however. If this is a problem, use `os.path.abspath`: `dirname(dirname(abspath(file)))`.

Comment: I know the OP knows about `dirname`. It isn't obvious to everyone that applying dirname to a directory yields the parent directory.

Comment: `dirname` does **NOT** always return the parent directory; http://twitter.com/#!/ActiveState/status/671049326788608

Comment: @Sridhar: That depends on your perspective; I consider a path ending in `/` as not representing the leaf directory entry itself, but its contents, which is why, e.g., `mv xxx yyy/` fails if `yyy` isn't a preexisting directory. In any case, even if we take your point as a given, it is irrelevant in the context of my answer. Neither `file` nor the result of `dirname` will ever end in a `/`.

Comment: Minor correction: `dirname` may return `'/'`, which clearly ends in a `/`. That is the only exception, AFAIK.

Answer (score 77):

Use **relative path** with the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module in Python 3.4+:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path(__file__).parent
```

You can use multiple calls to `parent` to go further in the path:

```
Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

As an alternative to specifying `parent` twice, you can use:

```
Path(__file__).parents[1]
```

Comment: If you need the path as a string because you want to modify it, you can just use `str(Path(__file__).parent)`.

Comment: It seems that in python 3.8.5 you need `Path(__file__).resolve().parent`

Comment: Thanks, I knew about `.parent` but not about `.parents`. IMO, that's much nicer than chaining `.parent` or `os.path.dirname`s.

Answer (score 69):

`os.path.abspath` doesn't validate anything, so if we're already appending strings to `__file__` there's no need to bother with `dirname` or joining or any of that. Just treat `__file__` as a directory and start climbing:

```
# climb to __file__'s parent's parent:
os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/../../")
```

That's far less convoluted than `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))` and about as manageable as `dirname(dirname(__file__))`. Climbing more than two levels starts to get ridiculous.

But, since we know how many levels to climb, we could clean this up with a simple little function:

```
uppath = lambda _path, n: os.sep.join(_path.split(os.sep)[:-n])

# __file__ = "/aParent/templates/blog1/page.html"
>>> uppath(__file__, 1)
'/aParent/templates/blog1'
>>> uppath(__file__, 2)
'/aParent/templates'
>>> uppath(__file__, 3)
'/aParent'
```

Comment: This is nice, but it would also be cool if the standard library added a convenience function that accomplished this...don't want to come to SO every time I need this func

Comment: Would `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__,  "..", "..")` be more portable?

Answer (score 15):

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Should give you the path to `a`.

But if `b.py` is the file that is currently executed, then you can achieve the same by just doing

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join('templates', 'blog1', 'page.html'))
```

Comment: o ,i know ,you are right ,and i want to get the a's parent folder. how to get it

Comment: @zjm1126: See Marcelo Cantos' answer. Apply `dirname()` twice. Everything you need now should be on this site.

Answer (score 9):

`os.pardir` is a better way for `../` and more readable.

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(given_path, os.pardir))
```

This will return the parent path of the given_path

Answer (score 6):

A simple way can be:

```
import os
current_dir =  os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(current_dir + "/../")
print parent_dir
```

Answer (score 3):

May be join two `..` folder, to get parent of the parent folder?

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"..",".."))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another relatively simple solution that:

- does not use `dirname()` (which does not work as expected on one level arguments like "file.txt" or relative parents like "..")
- does not use `abspath()` (avoiding any assumptions about the current working directory) but instead preserves the relative character of paths

it just uses `normpath` and `join`:

```
def parent(p):
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(p, os.path.pardir))

# Example:
for p in ['foo', 'foo/bar/baz', 'with/trailing/slash/', 
        'dir/file.txt', '../up/', '/abs/path']:
    print parent(p)
```

Result:

```
.
foo/bar
with/trailing
dir
..
/abs
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to jump to previous folder:

```
os.chdir(os.pardir)
```

If you need multiple jumps a good and easy solution will be to use a simple decorator in this case.

Answer (score 1):

from os.path import basename, dirname
basename(dirname('foo/bar/foo_bar'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think use this is better:

```
os.path.realpath(__file__).rsplit('/', X)[0]


In [1]: __file__ = "/aParent/templates/blog1/page.html"

In [2]: os.path.realpath(__file__).rsplit('/', 3)[0]
Out[3]: '/aParent'

In [4]: __file__ = "/aParent/templates/blog1/page.html"

In [5]: os.path.realpath(__file__).rsplit('/', 1)[0]
Out[6]: '/aParent/templates/blog1'

In [7]: os.path.realpath(__file__).rsplit('/', 2)[0]
Out[8]: '/aParent/templates'

In [9]: os.path.realpath(__file__).rsplit('/', 3)[0]
Out[10]: '/aParent'
```

Comment: Not quite, it's OS dependent (will not work on Windows). Also it does not allow to use relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))), os.pardir))
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer `pathlib` module, as mentioned in other answers, is, of course, the nicest method to parse and build paths, but you can get the parent also easily with the older `os.path` module:

```
os.path.split('a/b/c') # returns: ('a/b', 'c')
```

If you don't want the full path of the parent a/b, but just the name b, just call os.path.split a second time.