# beyond top level package error in relative import

Tags: python, import, package

It seems there are already quite some questions here about relative import in python 3, but after going through many of them I still didn't find the answer for my issue. 
so here is the question.

I have a package shown below

```
package/
   __init__.py
   A/
      __init__.py
      foo.py
   test_A/
      __init__.py
      test.py
```

and I have a single line in test.py:

```
from ..A import foo
```

now, I am in the folder of `package`, and I run

```
python -m test_A.test
```

I got message

```
"ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"
```

but if I am in the parent folder of `package`, e.g., I run:

```
cd ..
python -m package.test_A.test
```

everything is fine.

**Now my question is:** 
when I am in the folder of `package`, and I run the module inside the test_A sub-package as `test_A.test`, based on my understanding, `..A` goes up only one level, which is still within the `package` folder, why it gives message saying `beyond top-level package`. What is exactly the reason that causes this error message?

Comment: I have a thought here, so when run test_A.test as module, ‘..' goes above test_A, which is already the highest level of the import test_A.test, I think the package level is not the directory level, but how many levels you import the package.

Comment: I promise you will understand everything about relative import after watching this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/8682868.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid doing relative imports? Such as the way PyDev in Eclipse sees all packages within <PydevProject>/src?

Comment: Does your working dir also have an __init__.py?

Comment: See also: [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/4561887)

Answer (score 287):

EDIT: There are better/more coherent answers to this question in other questions:

- [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)
- [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912)

---

**Why doesn't it work?** It's because python doesn't record where a package was loaded from. So when you do `python -m test_A.test`, it basically just discards the knowledge that `test_A.test` is actually stored in `package` (i.e. `package` is not considered a package). Attempting `from ..A import foo` is trying to access information it doesn't have any more (i.e. sibling directories of a loaded location). It's conceptually similar to allowing `from ..os import path` in a file in `math`. This would be bad because you want the packages to be distinct. If they need to use something from another package, then they should refer to them globally with `from os import path` and let python work out where that is with `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH`.

When you use `python -m package.test_A.test`, then using `from ..A import foo` resolves just fine because it kept track of what's in `package` and you're just accessing a child directory of a loaded location.

**Why doesn't python consider the current working directory to be a package?** *NO CLUE*, but gosh it would be useful.

Comment: I've edited my answer to refer to a better answer to a question that amounts to the same thing. There is only workarounds. The only thing that I've actually seen work is what the OP has done, which is use the `-m` flag and run from the directory above.

Comment: It should be noted that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/4458173), from the link given by Multihunter, does not involve the `sys.path` hack, but the use of [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/), which is much more interesting in my opinion.

Comment: so the ".." in relative import is not as we usually think of ".." in the context of os? In os, .. simply mean step out the current dir and move to the parent dir, which is not the case in python's relative import. As you mentioned, the interpret discard the package information of current working directory. To me, as a developer who gets used to the os path concepts, it is little unintuitive :-(

Comment: "Why doesn't python consider the current working directory to be a package? NO CLUE, but gosh it would be useful." Rather than that, I wish it were possible to specify, *in conjunction with* the `-m` option, a path to the package root for the specified package.

Comment: How about the people who write python just fix this nonsense? And we can get  back to coding again.

Comment: @C.J. they know this is a problem but all the proposed solutions so far have some weird consequences and they tend to not accept changes when that's the case.

Answer (score 270):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..") # Adds higher directory to python modules path.
```

Try this.
Worked for me.

Comment: Umm...how woudl this work? Every single test file would have this?

Comment: The problem here is if, e.g., `A/bar.py` exists and in `foo.py` you do `from .bar import X`.

Comment: I had to remove the .. from "from ..A import..."  after adding the sys.path.append("..")

Comment: If script is executed from outside the directory it exists, this wouldn't work. Instead, you have to tweak this answer to [specify absolute path of the said script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19190695/3998252).

Comment: this is the best, least complicated option

Comment: @AlexR, I would rather say this is the easiest short-term solution, but certainly not the best.

Comment: But this gets nasty if you then perform isinstance checks on for instance classes defined in python files in the subdir, as they then have i prefix...

Comment: Bingo. Another option is to permanently add it to the path file.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. I explain why this happens and provide solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import/64310290#64310290

Comment: This does not generalize well, and is brittle (you end up with a lot of entries in the sys.path, and it isn't clear what order they'll be in, which makes it difficult to figure out which folders will be searched in what order). It causes a lot of problems if you want to have modules with the same name in different sub-packages. Like the Zen of Python says, `Namespaces are a honking great idea`, and this stomps on that.

Comment: This (`sys.path.append("..")`) only works _if you are inside the directory of the script you are about to run_, when you run it. Otherwise, you need to do this instead: assume you are running script `mydir/mypackage/myscript.py`, then you'd need to do `sys.path.append("mydir")` in order to give access to `mypackage`. However, if you are inside dir `mypackage` when you run the script, then you need to do `sys.path.append("..")` to give access to `mypackage`. The goal is to _give `myscript.py` access to `mypackage`, based relative to the directory you are in when you run `myscript.py`!_

Answer (score 57):

Assumption:
If you are in the `package` directory, `A` and `test_A` are separate packages.

Conclusion:
`..A` imports are only allowed within a package.

Further notes:
Making the relative imports only available within packages is useful if you want to force that packages can be placed on any path located on `sys.path`.

EDIT:

> Am I the only one who thinks that this is insane!? Why in the world is the current working directory not considered to be a package? – [Multihunter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import/30673795#comment81004804_30673795)

The current working directory is usually located in sys.path. So, all files there are importable. This is behavior since Python 2 when packages did not yet exist. Making the running directory a package would allow imports of modules as "import .A" and as "import A" which then would be two different modules. Maybe this is an inconsistency to consider.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that this is insane!? Why in the world is the running directory not considered to be a package?

Comment: Not only is that insane, this is unhelpful...so how do you run tests then? *Clearly the thing the OP was asking* and why I'm sure many people are here as well.

Comment: The running directory is usually located in sys.path. So, all files there are importable. This is behavior since Python 2 when packages did not yet exist. - edited answer.

Comment: I don't follow the inconsistency. The behaviour of `python -m package.test_A.test` seems to do what is wanted, and my argument is that that should be the default. So, can you give me an example of this inconsistency?

Comment: I'm actually thinking, is there a feature request for this? This is indeed insane. C/C++ style `#include` would be very useful!

Comment: "Why in the world is the running directory not considered to be a package?" First off: if I run `python ../sibling/script.py`, should Python assume `.` to be a package root? `../sibling`? Both? If both, in what order would they be chosen? Second: the entire point of *packages* is that they represent a coherent bundle of *installable* code; you aren't supposed to go prowling around directories like that, just like you don't normally go prowling around `C:\Program Files` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey "C/C++ style `#include`" is a *literal copy and paste of source code, prior to static compilation*. It bears no resemblance to a proper import system whatsoever. If you simply mean that it lets you specify a file path directly, you can do that just fine in Python (using the `importlib` standard library module, which is a wrapper around the `__import__` builtin function). In fact, Python gives you a wide variety of hooks into the import mechanism. `#include` is utterly primitive in comparison.

Comment: @Multihunter slamming my head against the wall tryna figure this out. I have no idea how this is acceptable lol

Answer (score 49):

None of these solutions worked for me in 3.6, with a folder structure like:

```
package1/
    subpackage1/
        module1.py
package2/
    subpackage2/
        module2.py
```

My goal was to import from module1 into module2. What finally worked for me was, oddly enough:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```

Note the single dot as opposed to the two-dot solutions mentioned so far.

---

Edit: The following helped clarify this for me:

```
import os
print (os.getcwd())
```

In my case, the working directory was (unexpectedly) the root of the project.

Comment: it's working locally but not working on aws ec2 instance, does it make any sense?

Comment: This worked for me as well--in my case the working directory was likewise the project root. I was using a run shortcut from a programming editor (TextMate)

Comment: @thebeancounter Same! Works locally on my mac but does not work on ec2, then I realized that I was running the command in a subdir on ec2 and running it at root locally. Once I run it from root on ec2 it worked.

Comment: `sys.path.append(".")` worked because you are calling it in parent directory, note that `.` always represent the directory where you run python command in.

Comment: This is called "Programming by coincidence" and it's absolutely awful. Don't do stuff you don't understand just because the code is working. It's absolutelty terrible this answer has so many votes.

Comment: Printing the `os.getcwd()` got me the idea to solve my issue! Thank you!

Comment: no idea why, but this worked for me

Comment: "In my case, the working directory was (unexpectedly) the root of the project." What did you expect to be the working directory instead? Why?

Comment: @HenryHenrinson  It's absolutely helpful.  Finding a solution even by happenstance allows those of us who have the time/interest/abilities to dig deeper to do so *at our leisure* .   Especially for a mostly arbitrary/ often illogical language like python.

Comment: Last edit is what made me understand it as well.

Answer (score 40):

**This is very tricky in Python**.

I'll first comment on why you're having that problem and then I will mention two possible solutions.

## What's going on?

You must take this paragraph from the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) into consideration:

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
> module. Since the name of the main module is always "**main**",
> modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
> must always use absolute imports.

And also the following from [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-name):

> Relative imports use a module's **name** attribute to determine that
> module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does
> not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '**main**')
> then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level
> module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file
> system.

Relative imports work from the filename (`__name__` attribute), which can take two values:

1. It's the filename, preceded by the folder strucutre, separated by dots.
   For eg: `package.test_A.test`
   Here Python knows the parent directories: before `test` comes `test_A` and then `package`.
   *So you can use the dot notation for relative import.*

```
#  package.test_A/test.py
from ..A import foo
```

You can then have like a root file in the root directory which calls `test.py`:

```
#  root.py
from package.test_A import test
```

2. When you run the module (`test.py`) directly, it becomes the entry point to the program , so `__name__` == `__main__`. The filename has no indication of the directory structure, so Python doesn't know how to go up in the directory. For Python, `test.py` becomes the top-level script, there is nothing above it. That's why you cannot use relative import.

---

## Possible Solutions

**A)** One way to solve this is to have a root file (in the root directory) which calls the modules/packages, like this:

[image]

- `root.py` imports `test.py`. (entry point, `__name__ == __main__`).
- `test.py` (relative) imports `foo.py`.
- `foo.py` says the module has been imported.

The output is:

```
package.A.foo has been imported
Module's name is:  package.test_A.test
```

**B)** If you want to execute the code as a module and not as a top-level script, you can try this from the command line:

```
python -m package.test_A.test
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.

You should also check: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912) , specially BrenBarn's answer.

Answer (score 22):

`from package.A import foo`

I think it's clearer than

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Comment: it's more readable for sure but still needs `sys.path.append("..")`. tested on python 3.6

Comment: Same as older answers

Comment: Switching to absolute imports like this does not solve the problem. It just causes a different type of `ImportError`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 16):

As the most popular answer suggests, basically its because your `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` includes `.` but not your path to your package. And the relative import is relative to your current working directory, not the file where the import happens; oddly.

You could fix this by first changing your relative import to absolute and then either starting it with:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/package python -m test_A.test
```

OR forcing the python path when called this way, because:

With `python -m test_A.test` you're executing `test_A/test.py` with `__name__ == '__main__'` and `__file__ == '/absolute/path/to/test_A/test.py'`

That means that in `test.py` you could use your absolute `import` semi-protected in the main case condition and also do some one-time Python path manipulation:

```
from os import path
…
def main():
…
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.path.append(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
    from A import foo

    exit(main())
```

Comment: "And the relative import is relative to your current working directory, not the file where the import happens" This is incorrect. The relative import is relative to where the import happens - that's why the error message is as OP describes. The `top-level package` is `test_A` in the error case, and the relative import tries to traverse into the parent `package` directory, *starting at the file, not the current working directory*.

Answer (score 13):

This is actually a lot simpler than what other answers make it out to be.

**TL;DR**: Import `A` directly instead of attempting a relative import.

The current working directory is not a package, **unless** you import the folder `package` from a different folder. So the behavior of your package will work fine if you intend it to be imported by other applications. What's not working is the tests...

Without changing anything in your directory structure, all that needs to be changed is how `test.py` imports `foo.py`.

```
from A import foo
```

Now running `python -m test_A.test` from the `package` directory will run without an `ImportError`.

### Why does that work?

Your current working directory is not a package, but it **is** added to the path. Therefore you can import folder `A` and its contents directly. It is the same reason you can import any other package that you have installed... they're all included in your path.

Comment: This only works incidentally, for the specific case of trying to start from `package/` (i.e. just inside the *intended* package root, rather than just outside).

Comment: @Karl This works **intentionally**. These are test files, and the goal is to be able to run them while developing the package (i.e., the root directory is **intentionally** the `package` directory). If the root directory is not `package` and you are importing `package` as a library, your intent is likely not to run the tests.

Answer (score 8):

Edit: 2020-05-08: Is seems the website I quoted is no longer controlled by the person who wrote the advice, so I'm removing the link to the site. Thanks for letting me know baxx.

---

If someone's still struggling a bit after the great answers already provided, I found advice on a website that no longer is available.

Essential quote from the site I mentioned:

> "The same can be specified programmatically in this way:
>
> import sys
>
> sys.path.append('..')
>
> **Of course the code above must be written before the other import**
>   **statement.**

It's pretty obvious that it has to be this way, thinking on it after the fact. I was trying to use the sys.path.append('..') in my tests, but ran into the issue posted by OP. By adding the import and sys.path defintion before my other imports, I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove `..` in test.py
For me pytest works fine with that

Example:

```
from A import foo
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, the credit goes to Chris Collett answer. It appeared a year before this one. Also his answer explains things properly (why it does work).

Answer (score 5):

if you have an `__init__.py` in an upper folder, you can initialize the import as
`import file/path as alias` in that init file. Then you can use it on lower scripts as:

```
import alias
```

Comment: `__init__.py` **has no bearing on the problem whatsoever**.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to change to this:
Solution 1(more better which depend on current py file path. Easy to deploy)
Use [pathlib.Path.parents make code cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39617732/4593553)

```
import sys
import os
import pathlib
target_path = pathlib.Path(os.path.abspath(__file__)).parents[3]
sys.path.append(target_path)
from utils import MultiFileAllowed
```

Solution 2

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from utils import MultiFileAllowed
```

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, I understand this question in this way:

[CASE 1] When you start an absolute-import like

```
python -m test_A.test
```

or

```
import test_A.test
```

or

```
from test_A import test
```

you're actually setting the **import-anchor** to be `test_A`, in other word, top-level package is `test_A` . So, when we have test.py do `from ..A import xxx`, you are escaping from the anchor, and Python does not allow this.

[CASE 2] When you do

```
python -m package.test_A.test
```

or

```
from package.test_A import test
```

your anchor becomes `package`, so `package/test_A/test.py` doing `from ..A import xxx` does not escape the anchor(still inside `package` folder), and Python happily accepts this.

In short:

- Absolute-import changes current anchor (=redefines what is the top-level package);
- Relative-import does not change the anchor but confines to it.

Furthermore, we can use [full-qualified module name](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html#searching)(FQMN) to inspect this problem.

Check FQMN in each case:

- [CASE2] `test.__name__` = `package.test_A.test`
- [CASE1] `test.__name__` = `test_A.test`

So, for CASE2, an `from .. import xxx` will result in a new module with FQMN=`package.xxx`, which is acceptable.

While for CASE1, the `..` from within `from .. import xxx` will jump out of the *starting node*(anchor) of `test_A`, and this is NOT allowed by Python.

[2022-07-19] I think this "relative-import" limitation is quite an ugly design, totally against (one of) Python's motto "Simple is better than complex".

Comment: This is way more complicated than it needs to be. So much for Zen of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in python 2.x but in python 3.6, assuming you are trying to run the whole suite, you just have to use `-t`

> -t, --top-level-directory directory
>   Top level directory of project (defaults to start directory)

So, on a structure like

```
project_root
  |
  |----- my_module
  |          \
  |           \_____ my_class.py
  |
  \ tests
      \___ test_my_func.py
```

One could for example use:

`python3 unittest discover -s /full_path/project_root/tests -t /full_path/project_root/`

And still import the `my_module.my_class` without major dramas.

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
package/
   __init__.py
   A/
      __init__.py
      foo.py
   test_A/
      __init__.py
      test.py
```

in `A/__init__.py` import `foo`:

```py
from .foo import foo
```

when importing `A/` from `test_A/`

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../A'))
# then import foo
import foo
```