# Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

[the code is not been working due to the error in assigning the path properly please help me with that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf3Ew.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import read this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your models:

```
#Remove the import statement: from blog.models import sighinmodel
#Then, inside your model
user = models.ForeignKey('blog.sighinmodel' , on_delete = None)
```

Also, I would like to point out that this is not the correct way of importing other modules in your models.py .

You should do like this:

```
from appname.models import ModelName
#for importing from another module's models.
```

There is no need for relative path names in import statements in Django. `from appname.module import function/class` works fine for nearly all the cases until cyclic redundancy occurs, in which you have to take one among many methods. One is the way I mentioned above:

**Method 1**: Simply put this inside the ModelClass. Don't import anything.

`user = models.ForeignKey('blog.sighinmodel' , on_delete = None)`

**Method 2**(when cyclic import condition is not arising)

```
from blog.models import sighinmodel
class SomeModel(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(sighinmodel , on_delete = None)
```

**NOTE:** The above will work only if a cyclic import isn't occurring. In case the cyclic import condition is occurring, switch back to the first method of declaration.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because relative imports are not allowed beyond top level package. Your blog is itself a module so if you import your model from there it would work.

```
from blog.models import User, sighinmodel
```

I would also suggest you to use CamelCase for your models name since they are classes for naming conventions.