# ImportError: No Module named util

Tags: python-3.x, cython, cythonize

My directory structure is like:

```
example1(folder)
    - util.pyd(file)
    - high.pyd(file)
example2(folder)
    -main_file.py(file)
```

Here, util.pyd and high.pyd files are in cython.

In addition, util.pyd is parent of high.pyd.

That means it uses a class of util.pyd as an object of its class. And then main_file.py imports classes from both util.pyd and high.pyd.

The issue what I am facing is:

In main_file.py, it imports class from Util.pyd correctly, but importing class from high.pyd, it is unable to find util.

Comment: Do you have it working with non-Cython python files (i.e. you look to be doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import))? Cython should be the same (hopefully) so if you can get it working with .py files that would be a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes it is working for .py files. And the problem is just when two of them are in cython and the main file is in python

Answer (score 0):

The following minimum, complete example works for me:

**example2/main_file.py**

```
from example1 import high
```

**example1/util.pyx**

```
class U:
    pass
```

**example1/high.pyx**

```
from . import util

class C(util.U):
    pass
```

I compiled util.pyx and high.pyx by changing to directory example1 and doing `cythonize -i util.pyx` and `cythonize -i high.pyx`

From the directory containing "example1" and "example" I ran `python3 -m example2.main_file` (which is the appropriate way to run a submodule as a script).

---

If this isn't enough information to get your code working I would suggest you edit your question to show *exactly* what you did.