# Python3 Relative Import Is not Working

Tags: python-3.x, relative-import

I'm new in python 3. I'm trying to run lark examples http://github.com/lark-parser/lark in a development mode, but was blocked on relative import problem.

```
lark
  |examples
  |     |
  |     |conf_lalr.py
  |
  |lark
  |  |
  |  |lark.py
     |
     |tools
     |    |
          |common.py
```

In conf_lalr.py, there's a line:
    from lark import Lark
Since I want use relative import, then I updated it with below methods:

1, from ..lark.lark import Lark

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conf_lalr.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..lark.lark import Lark
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

2, from .lark.lark import Lark

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conf_lalr.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .lark.lark import Lark
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.lark'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I searched lots of answers from internet, including stackoverflow. However, none is working.

Need someone tell why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing **init**.py files to make the folders as python packages.
Also for the first part , see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

To run the examples, you should do the following:

```
~$ cd lark

~/lark$ python -m examples.conf_lalr
```