# How to import file from parent directory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to import file from parent directory in python?

My project tree is as follows:

[image]

From `__main__.py` file which is in `vehiclesListCrawler` I want to import `common.py` which is in a parent directory.

Now I do it as follows:

```
from common import get_init_url, create_urls_to_fetch, MILEAGE_RANGES, notify_on_error
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "./__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from common import get_init_url, create_urls_to_fetch, MILEAGE_RANGES, notify_on_error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Nothing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) didn't help. That is why I've posted the new question.

Inside `__main__.py`I have main function as follows:

```
def main(params):
    try:
        process.crawl(AutoscoutListSpider, params)
        process.start()
        return {"Success ": main_result}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"Error ": e, "params ": params}
```

And I run it as follows:

```
main({"make":"Audi", "model":"A3", "mileage":"2500"})
```

Comment: try `from ..venv.common import ....`

Comment: @BearBrown That gives me `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874916/8060120

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score -1):

Way 1: absolute import:

```
from asCrawlers.common import get_init_url, create_urls_to_fetch, MILEAGE_RANGES, notify_on_error
```

Way 2: relative import:

```
from ..common import get_init_url, create_urls_to_fetch, MILEAGE_RANGES, notify_on_error
```

More on imports [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> When specifying what module to import you do not have to specify the
>   absolute name of the module. When a module or package is contained
>   within another package it is possible to make a relative import within
>   the same top package without having to mention the package name. By
>   using leading dots in the specified module or package after from you
>   can specify how high to traverse up the current package hierarchy
>   without specifying exact names. One leading dot means the current
>   package where the module making the import exists. Two dots means up
>   one package level. Three dots is up two levels, etc.

Comment: First one gave me the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asCrawler'`. And the second one `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: @Boky Not "asCrawler", but "asCrawlers" - didn't you mistype it?

Comment: I mistyped it here. I've copied your code. The same problem

Comment: @Boky How do you run this code? If you try to run ```__main__.py``` as a script, then scharette is right and the answer can be found in linked question (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158224/747744).

Comment: @Boky Could you please show exact code and error when updating ```sys.path``` before import?