# how to import a function from parent directory into test directory

Tags: python, file, testing, path, directory

I am trying to import a function from the directory in the same project.  how can i do that ?

```
.|____project/
 |     |_____src/
 |     |        |____myproject/
 |     |        |     | __init__.py
 |     |        |     |____funtion.py
 |     |_____test/
 |     |        |___ testmyproject.py
 |     |        |____data/
 |     |                 |___testdata
```

How can i import the the file function.py or the functions in the function.py file in my test/testmyproject.py to test the fucntions? i am not able to import the module from function.py

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Comment: and yes am using python 2.7

Comment: Here's the solution for pytest https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682126/3521881