# Import code to test form a same level directory

Tags: python, python-import

This is a nodejs and python project so the directory structure is the way it is.

This is my directory structure:

```
top_level/
    scripts/
        __init__.py
        python_script.py
        some_nodejs_files.js
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_python_script.py
```

I can put all my unit test code in the inside the `scripts` directory but I would like to put test code in the test directory which is at the same level as `scripts`. How do I import `python_scripts.py`  from `test_python_script.py`

From `tests/test_python_script.py` I've tried doing a `from ..scripts import python_script` but I get a `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

**EDIT:** After reading some of the links in the comments and trying some stuff out I added

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from scripts import python_script
```

and that seems to do the trick.

#### What I learned

Where ever you have the **init**.py that folder is the name of the module.

Comment: What does the ValueError say?

Comment: @Terminus Updated original post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Comment: Ok, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) is probably more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

```
# add scripts to the python path
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import sys
sys.path.append(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), 'scripts'))
```

Then your import will work.

Or take advantage of the fact that the current directory is already part of the path and just use a symbolic link:

```
# bash
cd tests
ln -s ../scripts/python_script.py
```

Then your import will work.

Comment: does that go into the __init__.py in the test directory?

Comment: Is your answer any different then my EDIT above? I guess its doing the same thing right