# Use a python package in the same project folder in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

**I created my customized package called 'dto' in my project folder.
But It does not recognize this package and module.**

How can I make my visual studio code to find it?

In Pycharm, if I create new package, it automatically detects that.

- I executed my simulator.py script in my simulation package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem. It seems visual studio code cannot automatically detect new python package. It has something to do with `$PYTHONPATH` configuration. I found an official reference from visual studio code documentation. Please have a look at this [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable).

1. adding a `dev.env` file inside your project

```
PYTHONPATH=${workspaceFolder}:${PYTHONPATH}
```

2. adding the following in your workspace `settings.json` config file

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"
```

This works for me. The debugger can find modules in the new package. Hopefully, this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see from the directory tree, you need to use a relative import(python >= 2.5):

```
from ..dto import price
```

Here the .. is used to specify that the import should be made from two folders up the current location of the script that is being invoked.

In your case, relative imports cannot be used as the files are in different packages. Please find the relevant post here [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. This error occurred.
Exception has occurred: ValueError
attempted relative import beyond top-level package
  File "C:\Users\lich_\Documents\aits\simulation\simulator.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..dto import PriceInfo

Comment: Can you check this again??

Comment: Oops, I might have jumped the gun there. Relative imports cannot be used beyond the current package. I have added the relevant answers to your question in my post.

Answer (score 0):

@Yossarian42's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56318080/286807) will work if you have a folder with your package name in the root of your project. However if your project follows the structure mentioned in [Py-Pkgs](https://py-pkgs.org/03-how-to-package-a-python) and uses a src dir like:

```
mypkg
├── CHANGELOG.md               ┐
...
├── pyproject.toml             ┐ 
├── src                        │
│   └── mypkg                  │ Package source code, metadata,
│       ├── __init__.py        │ and build instructions 
│       └── mypkg.py           ┘
└── tests                      ┐
    └── ...                    ┘ Package tests
└── examples                   ┐
    ├── mypkg_examples.py      │
    └── ...                    ┘ Package examples
```

In this case, you use the following for dev.env in your `workspaceFolder` (root):

```
PYTHONPATH=./src:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Create or edit `{workspaceFolder}/.vscode/settings.json` with:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

Full settings.json example:

```
{
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"
}
```

For debugging the `python.envFile` setting, you can print out the Python path with the following code:

```
import sys; print(f"sys.path: {sys.path}")
```