# How to import my own Python file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, import

Directory structure:

[image: Directory structure]

```
pwd
/Users/Mobile Documents/Pythonista3/Documents
```

I cannot import from my workspace: (`Documents/gfyc/gfyc.py` folder)

```
#! python3
from gfyc import gfyc

pass
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Pythonista3/Documents/youtube_mirror/youtube_mirror_bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gfyc import gfyc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gfyc'
```

**Visual studio code** `launch.json`:

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",

        # I have added the env line below
        "env" : {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"},
        "console": "externalTerminal",

    }
]
```

**Listing:**

```
[/Users/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~omz-software~Pythonista3/Documents]ls
```

**Output:**

```
__init__.py __pycache__  gfyc gym_helper.py  top_stories youtube_mirror
```

How can I import files from my workspace in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Please post the contents of the `gfyc` directory and your `__init__.py` files.

Comment: Is there any update on this question? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778741/use-a-python-package-in-the-same-project-folder-in-visual-studio-code) <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778741/use-a-python-package-in-the-same-project-folder-in-visual-studio-code