# Import and run a subpackage from within a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I'm looking for a way to import a subpackage from within a package in Python 3. 
Consider the following structure :

```
├── main.py
└── package
    ├── subpackage
    │   └── hello.py
    └── test.py
```

What I would like to do is use a function that inside hello.py from within test.py (which is launched by main.py)

#### main.py

```py
from package.test import print_hello

print_hello()
```

#### package/test.py

```py
from subpackage.hello import return_hello

def print_hello():
    print(return_hello())
```

#### package/subpackage/hello.py

```py
def return_hello():
    return "Hello"
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package.test import print_hello
  File "D:\Python\python-learning\test\package\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subpackage.hello import return_hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'
```

I tried putting a `.` in `test.py` and it worked, but my linter does not like it.

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

---

#### edit : I managed to use an absolute path as recommended but now when I try to put everything in a subfolder pylint is not able to import.

```
└── src
    ├── main.py
    └── package
        ├── subpackage
        │   └── hello.py
        └── test.py
```

[image]

Comment: And `from package.subpackage.hello` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
from .subpackage.hello import return_hello
```

instead of

```
from subpackage.hello import return_hello
```

in your test.py file and read [this](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) guide for better understanding how imports works in python.

You can see fixed result here : https://repl.it/@ent1c3d/SoupySadUnderstanding

Comment: That is exactly what my linter does not like as I said on my post

Comment: Okay, I understand, so you see answers on this question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import