# How to import models from outside Django BASE_DIR

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am working on a Django app in which I want to import some class/function from generator.py into my views.py to process an user-submitted input. My folder structure looks like this:

```
project/
   models/
      __init__.py
      generator.py
   web/
      django/
         __init__.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
         wsgi.py
      django_app
         __init__.py
         views.py
         etc.
```

Inside views.py, I have

```
from ...models.generator import Generator
```

When I try to run server, what I get is:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I've seen many answers, but most are about manipulating sys.path or changing PYTHONPATH. I'm not sure how and where to do either cause I'm rather new to Django.

Can someone tell me exactly which commands to run to allow the import to be done?

Comment: have you tried `from project.models.generator import Generator`

Comment: Yes it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'

Answer (score 1):

Import of python is based on `sys.path` and cannot be outside the top-level dir. [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import).

That's mean, if you append top of `BASE_DIR` path in `sys.path` you can import. But it's a tricky way.

```
def import_function():
    import sys
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR))
    module = __import__('models.generator')  # import code
    sys.path.pop()
    return module

g_module = import_function()
g_module.Generator
```