# Python Packaging issue

Tags: python-3.x, path, package, importerror

For some reason, I am unable to import a certain file. Here is my directory structure:

```
root_folder/
    program_to_run.py
    configuration/
        ..config files
     tools/
         __init__.py
         tools_to_use1/
             __init__.py
             dependencies/
                 __init__.py
                 helper_1.py
                 ... other .py files
             unit_tests/
                 _init__.py
                 helper_1_test.py
                 ... other unit tests for dependencies

         tools_to_use2/
             __init__.py
             hardware/
                 __init__.py
                 helper_2.py
                 ... other .py files
             ... other .py files
```

Where I am trying to import `helper_2.py` into `helper_1.py`

In helper_1.py I have the following import statement:

```
from tools_to_use2.hardware import helper_2.py
```

However, when I use `helper_1.py` in `program_to_run.py` (in the root folder) I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools_to_use2'
```

I'm assuming that it has to do with the way I am packaging my scripts? I followed the structure here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html (6.4 Packages) However, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

I have also tried adding the module to my PYTHON PATH, and I am still having not luck. I have also tried doing the sys.insert trick, but even that is not working for me.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import

Comment: @West I have tried some of those solutions, and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In short this is not possible. This post explains it https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673795/10054278 . If you'd like to do this you must find a work around. At the link I first shared there are a couple that could work. I suggest you restructure your project(s).