# What 'Attempted relative import beyond top-level package' error means in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7 and ran into a relative import error "Attempted relative import beyond top-level package" with the following folder structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── services
│   │   └── item_service.py
│   └── views
│       ├── home.py
│       ├── __init__.py
```

**My goal:** import variable *foo* from the top level *_init_.py* to *item_service.py* using

```
from .. import foo
```

Pylint gives the error when trying this.

However the same exact import statement works in *home.py*, and if I add a empty *_init_.py* file to the services folder, the import works.

So my my question is, why? Does python require your module to be in a subpackage in order to relatively import parent package's contents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Comment: Pylint may parse your code inside the package, while it should stay below the app level. If it's only pylint, I'd ignore it for now.

Comment: I think 0 0 is right. I have a project that runs fine, but pylint gives this error too.

Answer (score -1):

For me it got resolved in following ways:

1. First import the directory (import dir)
2. Then try to import the views/class (from dir import views/class)

Answer (score -5):

To solve:
Add **init**.py to all directories involved.

Add
sys.path.append("..")
BEFORE importing from sibling directory.