# How to fix 'attempted relative error' in my urls.py

Tags: python, django-urls

project
 a
  urls.py
 b
  views.py

The case is like this.
I am not being able to import the function from views.py in urls.py. It shows the error attempted relative import beyond top-level package.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

from ..b.views import function


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('function/', function),]
```

from ..b.views import function
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: Please import this as `from b.views import function`. Relative imports are usually not a very good idea (especially when you do a lot of "walking")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
from b.views import function
```

Answer (score 0):

In django, it is not recommended to use relative imports. You should import all files as they are present from the root of the django project. Example, for your case it should be:

```
from b import views
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the to-be-imported module or a reference is in the path of your python program. To include higher ordered dictionaries TRY:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..") # Adds higher directory to python modules path.
```

You might find your answer here [StackOverflow: ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

edit: other comments suggest that you should not use relative imports.