# How do i properly import relative path for unit testing

Tags: python

I have been reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) but i still can't figure out how to proper import so i can run coverage.

This is the structure of my app

```
package/
   app/
      services/
         __init__.py
         news_services.py
   test/
      news_test.py
```

This is the import

`from ..app.services.news_services import NewsServices`

This is the command that i run the file.

```py
coverage run .\test\news_test.py
```

And this is the error that i get

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT: here is an answer for an app/service

For testing within the same app/service I often use this pattern:

```py
import inspect
import os
import sys

test_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
src_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, '..', 'app')
sys.path.append(src_dir)

from services.news_services import NewsServices
```

### EDIT: Below is the original for *packages* but the question appears to relate to an app/service

Your best bet, and the one I use on a daily basis with packages that I maintain, is to **install your own package** and not use relative imports for this at all.

Your tests will find and import the package exactly as your users would.

Here is my `install.sh` which you only have to do once; the trick is installing it in an "editable" fashion which, in this context, will cause anything importing it from the environment to find it exactly in your working structure with all your local changes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

python3 -m venv env/
source env/bin/activate

pip install --editable "."
```

Then, within your tests:

```py
from app.services.news_services import NewsServices
```

This is also described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6466139/351084

Comment: i did all this and followed all the link that leads from this article but still i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: I should mention that in this case you are using a venv, and you need to *enter* the venv before running your code in order to find this dependency.  Something like `source env/bin/activate` and then `python myscript.py`

Comment: yes, i did activate venv it before i ran my script but still error.

Comment: Okay, follow-up question: are you actually making a *package*?  Do you have a setup.py?  I am starting to believe (and probably should have guessed earlier, from the name `app`) that you are not making a package (such as could be re-used and imported by other code) and instead are making an application/service/script that is intended to be used but not re-used.  I may have been misled by the top-level `package` folder.

Comment: I did create a `setup.py`  and you are correct, I am not making a package for reuse.