# How to correctly import a Python module in VS Code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I've recently started programming in Python and I've decided to code some Delphi functions in Python. I've decided to create a single Python module that holds my functions.

Now, I tried to import it, but I get this error in Visual Studio Code:

```
unable to import 'functions' pylint(import error) [5, 1]
```

Here is my code:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('/Users/user123/Desktop/Python/Functions/')

import functions
```

Here is an image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EGbk.jpg]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given your file/folder structure:

```
├── Functions
│   └── functions.py
├── <main app folder>
│   └── app.py
```

Although your imports may run correctly once you've added `path/to/Functions` to `sys.path`, Pylint is giving you that warning because that is not the recommended way of declaring imports, especially when you're importing modules *outside* the app package/folder.

From the [PEP8 Style Guide for Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable
> and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages)
> if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a
> directory inside a package ends up on `sys.path`):
>
> ```
> import mypkg.sibling 
> from mypkg import sibling 
> from mypkg.sibling import example
> ```

The recommended solution is to [setup `Functions` as a package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) by adding a `__init__.py` file under it:

```
├── parent
│   └── Functions
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── functions.py
```

then importing your functions like one of these:

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/parent")

# option 1
from Functions import functions
functions.copy()
functions.delete()

# option2
from Functions.functions import copy, delete
copy()
delete()
```

Both options should run correctly and satisfy PyLint.

Now, if you really want to do a non-absolute import like `from functions import func`, and get PyLint to accept that, I recommend renaming `functions.py` to something else. This is because, on some case-insensitive systems, importing `Functions` and `functions` could get treated as the same module. When you tell PyLint to look into `/path/to/Functions` (I'll show later), it might not be able to differentiate if `copy` and `delete` is part of `Functions` or of `functions`, and it might still show an import-error.

So, what you need to do is rename `functions.py` (ex. `filefuncs.py`):

```
├── Functions
│   └── filefuncs.py
├── <main app folder>
│   └── app.py
```

Then in you VS Code workspace, add this to your *.vscode/settings.json* file to tell PyLint where to look for the `filefuncs` module:

```json
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--init-hook",
    "import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to/Functions')"
]
```

Then you can now import it same as your original code but without PyLint errors:

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/Functions")
from filefuncs import copy, delete
copy()
delete()
```

The second way will get you what you need, but it contains some workarounds for PyLint to work. If you can use the recommended way I explained at the start, use that instead.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest example would be:

```
.
├── functions
│   ├── functions.py
└── main
    └── main.py
```

Now in the `functions/functions.py` I have:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def print_datetime():
    print(datetime.utcnow())
```

and in `main/main.py` I have:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(".")

from functions.functions import print_datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_datetime()
```

This `sys.path.append(".")` is helping you to switch the context from where you are calling the `main.py`, to be more accurate it adds higher directory to python modules path.

And while you are in the top-level directory of the project, you can now run the `main.py` which will produce a result like this:

```sh
(venv) user@pc: .../59702230 
$ python main/main.py 
2020-01-12 09:51:01.469436
```

For more details on how to do this, you can read a great QA in the [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import) where is a lot of great information on how to solve the same issue with different approaches.

I hope that it will help you!

Comment: Been struggling for  quite a while.....In vs code ..sys.path.append(".") helped me