# VS Code import Python module "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python

I am using VS Code to code in Python. Every time I try to import a Python module from a relative path, there is the above error. There is nothing wrong with the folder path. I have tried the relative path import in Pycharm and it works fine.

I read a few posts about a similar bug occurring in VScode about a year ago. Does anyone know the solution?

```
from folder1.python1 import hello
hello() # Simply should print "hello"


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'
```

The path `folder1.python1` is automatically intellisensed by the way.

Comment: check the path of vscode it should be in the folder where your .py file is.

Comment: can you share the "few posts about a similar bug occurring in VScode about a year ago"?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79612, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5660, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702230/how-to-correctly-import-a-python-module-in-vs-code (Solution about Pylint - Don't think directly related to path error)

Comment: Yeah the relative path is shown as folder1.python1, and works when I import a library but not .py modules.

Comment: it works. try updating vs code and run command from path_to_root_file>python caller.py

Comment: Yup I'm not using the newest version... that might help. In addition, could you elaborate what you mean by path_to_root_file>python caller.py? I haven't used that before.