# Importing classes - Python

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

Good morning I am stuck with the following problem. Precisely, I have the following setup:

```
Project_Name
|
|--> __init__.py
|
|--> Tool1
|      |
|      |--> Object1.py
|      |
|      |--> __init__.py
|
|--> Tool2
       |
       |--> Object2.py
       |
       |--> __init__.py
```

where Project_name, Tool1 and Tool2 are folders. Object2 contains a class named 'House'. How can I use the class 'House' in Object1? I tried the following:

```
from Tool2.Object2 import House
```

but I receive error message 'No module named 'Tool2'.

What am I doing wrong? All **init**.py files are empty, should I change that?

Comment: Where is the main script being executed? And how do you execute it? From terminal or IDE?

Comment: I will use Object1 inside another Project_name-subfolder (namely, the test folder). I use VSCode and its terminal.

Comment: try `from Project_Name.Tool2.Object2 import House`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1

If you are using VS code, the easiest fix is to start **your script being executed** like the following.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/PATH/TO/Project_Name')

import Tool1.Object1

...
```

## 2

Or, you can add the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to `settings.json` (can be found `ctrl + shift + P` then type `settings.json`)

```
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "/PATH/TO/Project_Name/"
    }
```

In this way, you can just

```
import Tool1.Object1
```

`sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` will do the same for you.

Comment: Seem still not working. Now I keep also having the error "unable to import" when I do: from Tool2.Object2 import House. Could it be related to the fact that I set PYTHONPATH=/PATH/TO/Project_Name?

Comment: I tested. Tell me the command you use to execute your main script.

Comment: I actually use the function "run in python terminal" of VSCode

Comment: If you are using VSCode, you might want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702230/how-to-correctly-import-a-python-module-in-vs-code

Comment: @YodaAndFriends Edited. Please check. :)

Comment: Still showing error. But it is working :')

Answer (score 0):

You need to export `PYTHONPATH` to your `Project_Name` so that the interpreter knows the specific folder(s) to look up.

```
export PYTHONPATH=path/to/your/project
```

For example:

object1.py

```
from tool2.object2 import House

house = House()
house.print_message("Hello World!!!")
```

object2.py

```
class House(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def print_message(self, text):
        print(text)
```

Outputs before and after exporting `PYTHONPATH`

```
$ python tool1/object1.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tool1/object1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tool2.object2 import House
ImportError: No module named tool2.object2

$ pwd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
/Users/.../StackOverflow

$ export PYTHONPATH=/Users/.../StackOverflow                                                                                                                                                                

$ python tool1/object1.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Hello World!!!

$ python object1.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Hello World!!!
```

Comment: Can you please be more precise? Where should I place the export statement?

Comment: You first need to open the terminal and change directory to your folder `Project_Name`. Next, use the `pwd` commandline to get the path to this folder (let's say X) and replace `path/to/your/project` with X to export.

Comment: Can you show me what do you get from this: `echo $PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: Sure: /Users/myName/Desktop/Origin/Project_Name

Comment: You should call the script from the `Project_Name` directory like this: `python Tool1/Object1.py` then it should work.