# Access parent module variable from sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

Need some help understanding importing packages in python 3. I have subdirectory with a module 'connection.py'. I need to access variables from parent directory module 'credentials.py'.  How would I refer this correctly? I have tried as
from benchchart.credentials import client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, access_code, access_token, refresh_token
which didn't quite work. This gives me an error 
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'benchchart''

[Screenshot for folder structure is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X6UA.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to import without a directory context, e.g.

```
from x import y
```

Python will look in the installed libraries directory `site-packages`.

To import local modules you need to specify it with a `.` for current directory or `..` for one directory above, e.g. because `credentials.py` is one directory up from `connections.py` you need to go up one level with `..`:

```
from ..credentials import client_id
```

And if you want to import from the `credentials.py` that is in the same directory, you specify it with `.`:

```
from .credentials import client_id
```