# Attempted relative import beyond top-level package with Python

Tags: python, django

I have seen several questions related to this error but I think they are different cases. My Django project has 2 applications and a directory structure like this and I'm facing an issue with relative imports I don't understand the logic.

Python allows me to import `market` from file `my_app2/signals.py` but it returns `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` if I import `portfolio` from file `my_app1/signals.py`. What is the reason and how can I found a wordaround?

```
/my_project
  /my_project
    __init__.py
  /my_app1
    market.py
    signals.py  #  Here I can't import portfolio.py
  /my_app2
    portfolio.py 
    signals.py  #  Here I can import market.py
```

my_app1/signals.py

```
from ..my_app2 import portfolio #  doesn't work
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

from my_project.my_app2 import portfolio #  doesn't work
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project.my_app2'
```

my_app2/signals.py

```
from ..my_app1 import market #  works
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import

Comment: I'm afraid this is not applicable to my case, `sys.path.append(".")` or `sys.path.append("..")` doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the issue without the use of `from`, it's not clear for me what was causing the error.

```
import my_app2.portfolio as portfolio
```