# Python sibling directory import errors

Tags: python, module, directory, package, python-import

My imports dont show any linting errors (flake8), but generate a ModuleNotFoundError when run.

The application can be started from either `__main__.py` or `bar.py`. Both modules call `bar.py`. The application seems to work when `__main__` is called, but I get the following error when running `bar`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:/Git/repo/lib/data/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.foo import classA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Directory structure

```
repo
└── lib
    ├── src
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __main__.py
    │   └── foo.py
    ├── data
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── bar.py
    └── __init__.py
```

main

```
from foo import classA
```

foo

```
class classA:
    def dostuff(x):
        ...
```

bar

```
from src.foo import classA
```

Comment: put `from foo import classA` in `__init__.py` and try accessing like `from ..src.foo import classA`

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting an import from a module, you need to make sure you're giving it context in relation to where the file you're importing is in the structure.

In `bar.py` you need to note that `data` is on the same level as `src` so you must go one level higher before you reference src: `from ..src.foo import ClassA`. `from src.foo` as in your question is equivalent to `from .src.foo` which would be searching for `foo` inside the `data` directory.

Comment: I'm now getting 
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: That is likely based on your PYTHONPATH not referencing the root of the project. This post may help you adjust: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import