# Import from different folder/module in python

Tags: import, python-import

I have the following structure of folders

```
project\
       main.py

       datasets\
                __init__.py
                custom_data.py
       models\
                __init___.py
                model1.py
                model2.py
                func.py
```

I would like to import func.py inside custom_data. (without using auxiliary libraries)

the main function imports custom_data.py with:

```
from datasets.custom_dataset import build as build_dataset
```

And when the code is running custom_dataset it fails to find the module func

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func'

I have already tried anything I saw here in stackoverflow:

from ..models import func
from project.models import func

I even tried to copy func.py as a duplicate inside datasets, but it doenst work at all (it does work when I use the func functions inside the custom_data.py, but does not when I call it from the main.py file).

Can anyone help me? Is it because I'm using windows maybe?
I know I can find a lot of other questions related to this but none have helped me at all.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your directory structure looks fine. However, you should rename `models/__init___.py` to `models/__init__.py`.

As for this line:

```
from datasets.custom_dataset import build as build_dataset
```

I assume you meant:

```
from datasets.custom_data import build as build_dataset
```

since your filename is `custom_data.py` and not `custom_dataset.py`.

Finally, as for importing `func` inside `custom_data.py`, all you would need to do is this:

```
from models import func
```

inside `custom_data.py`.

The reason why this:

```
from ..models import func
```

doesn't work is because "relative" imports like this only work properly inside a *package*. Its more or less explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import) answer so I won't repeat the details here.

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: Actually it all worked just fine once I added the PYTHONPATH, it's been a while I did not quite remembered. Thank you