# Python + Submodules: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-submodules, python-module, pipenv

I've been struggling with relative imports on python.

My project structure looks like this:

```
root_dir
├── main.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── unit_tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_first.py
│   └── test_second.py
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── first.py
    ├── second.py
    └── third.py
```

I want to import a set of functions from a file that is located in `my_package` into `test_first.py`.

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) the syntax should be the following:

```
from ..my_package import first
```

When I do that, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dev/root_dir/my_package/unit_tests/first.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..my_package import first
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have also tried to import the file by using the following syntax:

```
from root_dir.my_package import first
```

When I do that, I get the following exception:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'root_dir'
```

It is important to mention that I am using `pipenv` to handle the virtual environment.
Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll give you the code that worked for me. Then, I'll give a brief explanation. Here's a short function that should let you import from the root directory.

#### Solution

```py
import os, sys

def access_root_dir(depth = 1):
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
    args: list = [parent_dir]
    for _ in range(depth):
        args.append('..')
    
    rel_path = os.path.join(*args)
    sys.path.append(rel_path) 

# At the top of test_first.py
access_root_dir(2)
import root_dir
```

Since the root directory is a grandparent of `test_first.py`, you need to go to depth 2:

#### Explanation

I encountered the same problem in one of my projects and found
that imports from a parent directory were fixed by altering the `sys.path`. Appending an absolute path to the root directory with something like
`sys.path.append(abs_path_to_root)` doesn't seem to work unless everything is part of a package. Python won't access parent directories in imports by default.

```py
# Case 1: Relative path to parent - works
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
relative_path = os.path.join(current_dir, '..')
sys.path.append(relative_path)
import parent_module_name # This works for me (Python 3.9)

# Case 2: Absolute path to parent - Doesn't work 
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
import parent_module_name # raises ModuleNotFoundError
```

Answer (score 2):

I Think the issue is that your root directory is not considered a python module.

In order to do the relative import you should add "__init__.py" to your root directory.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 1):

The [current working directory is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673795/11633985). Use `os.getcwd()` to see what it is, but it is likely going to be `root_dir`.

In that case, you can import top-level packages directly by name without a relative import; you should directly import from `my_package`, like so:

```py
from my_package import first
```

...or:

```py
from my_package.first import do_something
```

Replicated file tree:

```
root_dir
├── main.py
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── first.py
└── unit_tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_first.py
```

Contents of `main.py`:

```py
from unit_tests import test_first

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_first.test_something()
```

If you attempt to do a relative import, i.e.,: `from ..my_package import first` you'll get:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports are only allowed within a package. A package must be self-sifficient and only relies on Standard Library or third-part packages either in global or virtual environment 'lib' folder. A package is required not to access any python mpdule around it, meaning a module inside of package must not import anything outside the top level folder of the package in a relative manner. To specifies top level folder of a package create `__init__.py` file at the root of it and put the following code inside of it:

```
# Marking the containing folder the top level folder of the package...
__package__ = ''
```

In your example you can have two packages: 'root_dir' and 'my_package'.
So create `__init__.py` at 'root_dir' and you've already created `__init__.py` in 'my_package' and put the following inside of them:

```
# Marking the containing folder the top level folder of the package...
__package__ = ''
```

And now you can have the following relative import:

```
from ..my_package import first
```