# Import not working inside folder (Module not found / Import Error)

Tags: python, import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I have seen this question in many pages and also here but I have tried everything and I can't seem to make it work so I need a second opinion please :(

I have the following structure in my code:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRAZK.png)
It looks like this:

```
ODS/
|__init__.py
|example.py
├── mqtt_model/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mqtt_class.py
└── python-can/
    ├── can-venv/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── mqtt_can_logger.py
    ├── read.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── write.py
```

What I want to do is import a class (`MQTT_Model`) inside `mqtt_class.py` to `mqtt_can_logger.py`

In my `mqtt_model/__init__.py` I have
`from .mqtt_class import MQTT_Model`

`python_can/__init__.py` is an empty file and I want to import the MQTT_Model to `mqtt_can_logger.py`.

This import is not working but in `example.py` it does work with `from mqtt_model import MQTT_Model`
It's just inside the `python-can` directory that's not working!

I have tried doing relative and absolute paths like:

```
from mqtt_model.mqtt_class import MQTT_Model
from .mqtt_model.mqtt_class import MQTT_Model

from ..mqtt_model import MQTT_Model
from .mqtt_model import MQTT_Model
from mqtt_model import MQTT_Model
```

Nothing works ;( i keep getting eitherI mport Error: attempted relative import with no known parent package or ModuleNotFound: no module named 'mqtt_model'

Comment: Hi, Adriana! Do you already take a look at this answer? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/66964999/2933186

Comment: Hi Giba! I checked it but what I do not want is to use os and sys :( I have done what I said in my question before but I am doing it exactly as I did before so I don't know what's happening! :(

Comment: Try do this: (at `ODS/` folder): `python path.to.my.run_file.py`. Maybe works! =)

Comment: it doesnt :(((((((((((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**:
I assume that your import problem is caused by running your program from virtual environment created in the `can-venv` folder. So, the `python-can` folder becomes the root folder of the project. It makes interpreter unable to find the modules and packages outside this directory. To overcome this problem you should either recreate the virtual environment for you project in the `ODS/` folder or add extra paths by `sys.path.insert` following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/22561467):

```py
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/ODS/')

# OR

sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/ODS/mqtt_model')
```

Then, you could import modules and packages from `ODS/` folder:

```py
from mqtt_model.mqtt_class import MQTT_Model  # sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/ODS/')

# OR

from mqtt_class import MQTT_Model   # sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/ODS/mqtt_model')
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add that in the things I have tried! I tried that but still nothing works! I just don't understand why it does outside the folder but inside python_can it doesn't!! :(

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. How did you launch your program? Did you activate virtual environment from `can-venv` folder?

Comment: It did work!!! I misread and added from mqtt_model import MQTT_Model, I did not try just the mqtt_class with the the sys! Thank you so much! I do wonder though why it still didn't work after I deleted the can-venv folder to just have the python_can as the root, but with import sys it worked thanks!

This is what I used:
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/ODS/mqtt_model')
from mqtt_class import MQTT_Model