# How to import module from one directory to another?

Tags: python

I am trying to import python module from one directory to another directory but not able to do it.

Here is my folder structure

```
Parent_Folder
---------Module1
         ----__init__.py (empty file)
         ----mymodule1.py
---------Module2
         ----__init__.py (empty file)
         ----mymodule2.py
```

I am trying to import

`mymodule1.py`

into

`mymodule2.py`

Here is the command that I have used to import the python module:

```
import Module1.mymodule1
```

but getting an error like

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Module1'
```

I do see there are option like system-path at runtime, `PYTHONPATH` but I don't want to use those options.

Do you all have any other recommended solutions?

Comment: You can also add the path to the other module to `sys.path` before `import`ing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert this at the top of module1.py, or in the **init**.py in Module1 if you're importing module1.py as well:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../Module2") #assuming linuxOS 
import module2
```

This adds the Module2 directory to the system path and allows you to import files as if they were local to your current directory.

Other answers can be found in this link: [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30669474/10475762)

Comment: Also, this seems to cover pretty much everything: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/10475762

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you an example of importing modules

**I created the module1.py file**

```
print("Module : 1")
def module01():#function
    print("module : 1.2")

class Module02:# class
        def module021(self):# function
            print('MODULE 1')
```

to import you need to indicate the file name

**module2.py**

```
from module1 import  module01 #import the function
from module1 import  Module02 #importing the class from module2.py




module01()
mod1 = Module02() #
mod1.module021()# imported class function
```