# Import Python modules between directories at the same level

Tags: python

My project structure:

[image: Project structure]

In `XMLHelper.py` file under the `Utility` package, I have the below import:

```
from ..Common import BaseScreen
```

From Pycharm I right click the `ResultSettingScreen.py` to run the script.

I get error below:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 xxxx/src/FiveInch/800x480/ResultSettingScreen.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "xxxx/src/FiveInch/800x480/ResultSettingScreen.py", line 22, in <module>
        from Utility import XMLHelper
      File "xxxx/src/FiveInch/800x480/Utility/XMLHelper.py", line 5, in <module>
        from ..Common import BaseScreen
    ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)