# How i can fix ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python

I have a project structure like this:

```
cartesianproduct
    test
         __init__.py
         test_cartesian_product.py
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    main.py
    sequence_creation.py
    sequences_operations.py
```

In `test_cartesian_product.py` I import

```
from .. import sequences_operations
from .. import sequence_creation
```

In `__main__.py` I import `from tests import test_cartesian_product_package` and running `test_cartesian_product_package.running_tests()`
But at startup `__main__.py` i get an error

```
from .. import sequences_operations
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

If I just run `test_cartesian_product.py` i get the same error.
How to fix it?

Comment: just simply write `import sequences_operations` in `test_cartesian_product.py`

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import

Comment: @sahasrara62 IDE tells me "No module named 'sequences_operations'"

Comment: @NaveenkumarM I tried some advice from there and the error didn't go away

Comment: have you followed the one with utmost upvotes

Comment: @Nitrolacs Why are you using a `__main__.py` file? That is only meant to be used for running modules with `python -m`. Anyway, the way to solve all import problems like this is to use a startup script that is *outside of the top-level package* (and in the same directory). That script must then only use *absolute imports*, so as to act as a base for all relative imports within the package. Usually, it is very minimal, and just contains something like `if __name__ == '__main__': import sys; from toplevelpkg import mod; sys.exit(mod.run())`.