# Python - Module Not Found Error when running main function in secondary folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner with Python. Before I start, here is my python folder strcuture.

```
-project
---main.py
---secondary-folder
----------new_main.py
---model
----------__init__.py
----------abc.py
```

Under `project` folder I have a `model` folder which has two python files `__init__.py` and `abc.py` which contents follow:

```
class ABC:
    def print_abc(self):
          print("abc")
```

Next in my `main.py` and `new_main.py` are the same contents:

```
from model.abc import ABC

if __name__ == "__main__":
   ABC().print_abc()
```

Whenever I run `python3 ./secondary-folder/new_main.py` under `project` folder it results in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./secondary-folder/new_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from model.abc import ABC
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

But the terminal can print out `abc` if I run `main.py` under `project` folder.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to import something the code is seeking from the folder you have run the file in.

So in folder `secondary-folder` you have no module (folder) named `model`. You have to leave that folder with calling parent folder, `project` in this case.

Try this in `new_main.py`:

```
from project.model.abc import ABC

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ABC().print_abc()
```

Answer (score 0):

After I do some researches, I have got an idea from this link [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

All project folders have to add **ini**.py like the structure below:

```
-project
---__init__.py
---main.py
---secondary-folder
----------__init__.py
----------new_main.py
---model
----------__init__.py
----------abc.py
```

Then run the command `python secondary-folder.new_main` Everything will be fine.

Comment: Yes, this is useful if you want to 'travel' often between levels :)