# Import functions from another directory

Tags: python, directory, path, sys

I am running a python script (app.py) where I have to use two functions from another script (src.py), located inside another directory. The structure is the following:

```
Dir:
   Dir_1:
        __init__.py
        src.py
   Dir_2:
        app.py
```

I am using, in app.py, the following lines:

```
from pathlib import Path
PROJECT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT = PROJECT/'Dir_1'

import sys
sys.path.insert(1, PROJECT)
from src import odd_all, even_all
```

to access to the functions `odd_all`, `even_all` declared inside `src.py`. However, I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The issue was that PROJECT is a Posixpath object, while SYS accepts only strings. Therefore, the solution was just to transform PROJECT to string:

```
from pathlib import Path
PROJECT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT = str(PROJECT)+'/Dir_1'

import sys
sys.path.insert(1, PROJECT)
from src import odd_all, even_all
```

Now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sys.path.append()` to append the path of your file to the system's path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/.../Dir/Dir_1')

from src import odd_all, even_all
```

Comment: It still gives the same error message.

Comment: Check the naming of src