# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package, no red lines on code

Tags: python, python-import

I know many people asked this question but I still can't figure this out.

My Project setup:

[project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj3sV.png)

I'm trying to import Reservations.py in queries.py

I did:

```
from ..entities import Reservation
```

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..entities/')
from entities import Reservation
```

any ideas??

the first thing I tried looks good before I run it, but when I try to run it says:

`ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: Please include your full project structure as text rendering, and also you have omitted where `queries.py` actually is.  Moreover, it appears that wherever the `queries` module lies (I assume either `data_analysis` or `sql_dir`) is already a top level module so that's the source of the error.

Comment: That is correct, queries.py lies in sql_dir , so how can I make it work?
I also put a better picture in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Comment: I don't really understand what they are talking about, I don't want to execute the imported file, just to use the class in there.
I removed the dots, now it looks like it works, but it is underlined red in PyCharm, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: try using -

from Hotel Reservations.entities import Reservations

Comment: Unresolved reference Hotel Reservations
Unresolved reference entities

Comment: In that case you need to give your project directory  path in `Mark Directory As` -> `Source Root` in PyCharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario will work, If you are in the `Hotel Reservation` directory,  `sql_dir` and `entities` are separate packages.

Conclusion:
..entities imports are only allowed within a package.

You can try -

```
from Hotel Reservations.entities import Reservation
```

You also need to give your project directory path in `Mark Directory As` -> `Source Root` in PyCharm

Comment: This answer worked, but I have to add that I used the same imports I had initially, just without the dots.