# Sphinx Auto-API Exception: Relative import with too many levels (1) for module 'api'

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

First time asking a question on here so apologies if I miss some detail.

I'm running sphinx auto-api to generate docs, this has always worked on this project but it's now complaining about some imports in one of the site packages.

Command:

```
sphinx-build -b dummy docs docs/_build/html --keep-going
```

I'm not sure what's going on. In my `conf.py` file I have the following line:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
```

I'm running it on a poetry environment.

This is the error I'm seeing.

```
[AutoAPI] Reading files... [ 11%] /Users/marta/PycharmProjects/app/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests-stubs/api.pyi                                                                           
Extension error (autoapi.extension):
Handler <function run_autoapi at 0x107c7da20> for event 'builder-inited' threw an exception (exception: Relative import with too many levels (1) for module 'api')
```

Versions of sphinx packages:

```
Sphinx = "^6.1.0"
sphinx-rtd-theme = "^2.0.0"
sphinx-pydantic = "^0.1.1"
sphinx-autoapi = "^3.0.0"
```

Comment: Do you still have imports like this `from ..X import Y` ? As stated here, it might be an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import#answer-45874916

Comment: The error seems to be related to [types-requests](https://pypi.org/project/types-requests/). Does anything change if you uninstall this library and run sphinx-build again?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a go. However, it is required by another package:
 name         : types-requests            
 version      : 2.31.0.20231231           
 description  : Typing stubs for requests 

dependencies
 - urllib3 >=2

required by
 - djangorestframework-stubs >=0.1.12

It seems to be complaining about the imports in a specific file in types-requests, but obviously that I cannot change. Don't understand what has changed for it to fail now with docs.

Comment: I've tried removing the types-requests package but still the same error.

Comment: OK, maybe you can try to uninstall `djangorestframework-stubs`?

Comment: Thanks, yes I have tried that and same error.

Comment: I found the "Relative import with too many levels" message in the source code of astroid (used by pylint): https://github.com/pylint-dev/astroid/blob/main/astroid/exceptions.py#L113.

Comment: I think you should ask this question at the [sphinx-autoapi](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx-autoapi/issues) issues tracker because the error seems to be specific to their extension. It's not a common Sphinx vanilla issue and so most readers here are unlikely to use that extension.