# Django grabing before the BASE_DIR path

Tags: django

I am trying to set my static file before the `base_dir` file

like,
My root dir is `Desktop/afolder/projectdir/settings.py`

and my current static file in `Desktop/afolder/static/blabla.js`

And grab it like with

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Above those works great, but now i am changing my `static` file dir, it will be now before the base dir

like: `Desktop/static/blabla.js`

In this case, i am in trouble to configure my setting so that it get my static files. coz, it is before the base dir, my base dir is `afolder` like `Desktop/afolder/projectdir/settings.py`

Can anyone help me to recognize the static file of this dir `Desktop/static/blabla.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Unipath`. It gives you a convenient object-oriented approach to define paths:

```
from unipath import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)

# Another way:
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

You can install it using `pip3 install unipath`.

Comment: is not it passable to deal without any third party library?

Comment: You can fiddle with the built-in `os.path` or `pathlib`, but there is little reason to do so. Unipath is a mature and convenient library. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817264/how-to-get-the-parent-dir-location

Comment: `pathlib` already includes parent(s) methods, it isn't any harder https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html