# How get path of specific parent directory in python

Tags: python

I have `path = "dir1/dir2/dir3/file.py"`

I need a way to get the full path to `dir2` i.e. `dir1/dir2`.

something like `findparent(path, 'dir2')`.

Comment: `path.split('dir2')[0]` ?

Comment: @venky__ This will not output what he wants.

Comment: @venky__ thank you for your answer, I am looking for a builtin function like `os.path.findparent`, I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the path by the target directory, take the first element from the list, and then add the target directory to the target path.

```
path = "dir1/dir2/dir3/file.py"

def findparent(path: str, dir_: str) -> str:
    return path.split(dir_)[0] + dir_

print(findparent(path, 'dir2'))
# dir1/dir2
```

Comment: I look for this exactly but without the need to define the function myself, if no one would mention a builtin function that does the same then I would mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: @Tomergt45 Sababa. Also, I added the `path: str` to point the datatype that the function needs to get. And the `-> str` points the datatype that the function will return.

Comment: Ahla :) And I understood that but because this is a small function there isn't really a need to declare types

Comment: @Tomergt45 This is my writing style (';

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) and the path actually exists:

```
path.resolve().parent
```

Just `path.parent` also works, purely syntactically, but has some caveats as mentioned in the docs.

To find one specific part of the parent hierarchy, you could iteratively call `parent`, or search [`path.parents`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) for the name you need.

Comment: `.parent` would just return the path to the parent directory, not to `dir2`, isn't it?

Comment: Right, I missed that requirement initially.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current work directory is at the same location as your `dir1`, you can do:

```
import os
os.path.abspath("dir1/dir2")
```

Comment: My working directory is `dir3` so `abspath('dir1/dir2')` is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this out! [How to get the parent dir location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817264/how-to-get-the-parent-dir-location)

My favorite is

```
from pathlib import Path

Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent # ad infinitum
```

You can even write a loop to get to dir2, something like this..

```
from pathlib import Path
goal_dir = "dir2"
current_dir = Path(__file__)
for i in range(10):
    if current_dir == goal_dir:
        break
    current_dir = current_dir.parent
```

Note: This solution is not the best, you might want to use a while-loop instead and check if there is actually a parent. If you are at root level and there is no parent, then it doesn't exist. But, assuming it exists and you don't have a tree deeper than 10 levels, this works.