# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable with path

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am facing this issue, but I couldn't figure out why because I don't know where something changes to str. I am using python 3.6 . This function is supposed to detect a face.

The error is detected in this line

**person_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path(path)))**

**Code:**

```
    def extract_face(path_to_filename, detector, required_size=(160, 160), save_faces=True):
        image = Image.open(path_to_filename)
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        pixels = asarray(image)
        results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
        x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']
        x1, y1 = abs(x1), abs(y1)
        x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
        face = pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        image = Image.fromarray(face)
        image = image.resize(required_size)
        if save_faces:
            path = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path_to_filename))[0]
            file_name = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path_to_filename))[1]
            person_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path(path)))
            project_folder = path(path).parent.parent
            print(person_name)
            target_folder = os.path.join(project_folder, 'faces_mini_dataset', person_name)
            if not os.path.exists(target_folder):
                os.makedirs(target_folder)
            target_face_file_path = os.path.join(target_folder, file_name)
            print(target_face_file_path)
            image.save(target_face_file_path)
        face_array = asarray(image)
        return face_array
```

**error**:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

**fulltrace:**

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:74: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:517: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4138: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3976: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:174: The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:181: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

2020-12-30 01:02:58.905653: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-12-30 01:02:58.926680: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2299965000 Hz
2020-12-30 01:02:58.927412: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x484d980 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-12-30 01:02:58.927467: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2020-12-30 01:02:59.110157: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
Extracting faces from /home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/persons_dataset/zakir/ .....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/face_detector.py", line 85, in <module>
    faces, labels = generate_faces_from_images(persons_dataset_path)
  File "/home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/face_detector.py", line 74, in generate_faces_from_images
    faces1 = extract_faces(path)
  File "/home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/face_detector.py", line 59, in extract_faces
    face = extract_face(path, detector, save_faces=True)
  File "/home/mani/Downloads/dip_1/face_detector.py", line 38, in extract_face
    person_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path(path)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the full traceback

Comment: @Mureinik updated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by calling `path(path))`?

Comment: `path` is a string, you can't `call` a string like `path()` as you've attempted to do with `path(path)`

Comment: it is all about to create a directory with faces_mini_dataset and out detected face inside it in case of save,

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the problem, you can accept it by clicking the gray checkmark next to it.

Comment: (the answer that starts with "The problem is in... "

Comment: This is not an ad. Please accept my answer

Answer (score 3):

I am learning Python myself. Zixuan is right, but I'd like to add the following about using `os.path` to get the parent directory of your given one.

You might want to use something like this:

```
import os

def extract_face(path_to_filename):
  my_path = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path_to_filename))[0]
  print(my_path)
  parent = os.path.dirname(my_path)
  print(parent)

extract_face("path.py")
```

Found on SO in [how-to-get-the-parent-dir-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817264/how-to-get-the-parent-dir-location) and then in the [Python os.path Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).

Another way could be:

```
from pathlib import Path

def extract_face(path_to_filename):
  path = Path(path_to_filename)
  print(path.parent.parent)

extract_face("path.py")
```

Found in [pathlib Doc - new since 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

I have removed some information I don't have from your method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `path(path)`. It is not clear whether you are trying to call a function and accidentally called a string or you wanted to call a string, but you can't call a string. A string is not the same as a function. Hence the error.